# Solving $y'' - y' -2y=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$y'' - y' -2y=0$$

I've a solution that believe is wrong. I also  have the correct solution, so this isn't a question about how to solve the above equation, but my question is, what's wrong with this solution:

Characteristic polynom:

$$r^2-r-2 = (r-1/2)^2-(-1/2)^2-2 = (r-1/2)^2 - 1/4 - 8/4 = (r-1/2)^2 - 9/4 =$$

$$=(r-1/2+3i/2)(r-1/2-3i/2)$$

Which should lead to:
$$y = e^{x/2}(A \cos x + B \sin x)$$

Comment: $r^2-r-2=(r+1)(r-2)$

Comment: The imaginary term shouldn't be there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last step is wrong. Notice that you have $(r-a)^2 - b^2$ which leads to $(r-a+b)(r-a-b) = (r-2)(r+1)$ .

Hence, the solution of the ODE is given by:

$$y(x) = A e^{r_1} + B e^{r_2} = A e^{2x} + B e^{-x}$$

Cheers!